# 'Delay' na atribuição/existência de propriedades na instância vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```js
Vue.component('child-comp', {
  template: '<p>Child here</p>',
  props: ['item'],
  methods: {
     alt: function(msg) {
     alert(msg);
     }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
     return {
        item: null
     }
  },
  methods: {
     load_child: function() {
        this.item = true;
        this.$refs['comp1'].alt(this.item.toString());
     }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="load_child">execute child</button>
  <child-comp v-bind:item="item" v-if="item != null" ref="comp1"></child-comp>
</div>
```

Como se pode ver ao primeiro clique dá erro, dizendo:

> Cannot read property 'alt' of undefined / TypeError: this.$refs.comp1 is undefined

Quando na partir da linha anterior este componente (`this.item = true;`) deveria já existir/ser *defined*

Para contornar isto eu fiz:

```js
Vue.component('child-comp', {
  template: '<p>Child here</p>',
  props: ['item'],
  methods: {
     alt: function(msg) {
     alert(msg);
     }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
        item: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
     load_child: function() {
        this.item = true;
        setTimeout(() => {this.$refs['comp1'].alt(this.item.toString());}, 100);
     }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="load_child">execute child</button>
  <child-comp v-bind:item="item" v-if="item != null" ref="comp1"></child-comp>
</div>
```

Mas não quero nem me parece de todo ser o correto.

Procuro uma alternativa a isto, será que implementei mal alguma coisa, ou deveria ter feito algo que não fiz/sei que existe.

Comment: Não seria suficiente correr `this.alt()` dentro do `mounted` do `child-comp`?

Comment: Sim @Sergio , neste caso que coloquei sim, mas no projeto que estou a fazer vão haver argumentos a entrar em "`alt()`", que são dinâmicos e variam consoante o componente pai

Comment: Ainda assim acho que devias usar `props`. Estar dependente de assincronismo pode dar problemas. Se `alt()` fôr assíncrona isso vai dar outros problemas.

Comment: @Sergio, tudo bem eu acredito e sei que sabe o que está a dizer. Mas poderia dar um exemplo do que seria a sua solução, como resposta. Aceitei aquela pois me parece a mais indicada até agora. Editei a resposta para que `alt()` recebesse argumentos

Comment: Dei uma resposta com o que faria no caso que me parece ser o teu. Se a pergunta for mais detalhada é mais fácil responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em casos parecidos eu costumo usar arrays, passar o conteúdo por `props` e mostrar os elementos no DOM dependendo dessa array. Assim fica tudo sequencial, sem possíveis condições de corrida.

```js
Vue.component('child-comp', {
  template: '<div><h3>{{item.title}}</h3><p>{{item.body}}</p></div>',
  props: ['item']
});
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/';
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      postNr: 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    load_child: function() {
      axios.get(url + this.postNr++)
        .then(res => this.items.push(res.data))
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.0/axios.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>



<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="load_child">load post</button>
  <child-comp :item="item" :key="item.id" v-for="item in items"></child-comp>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Sérgio, postei uma pergunta há algum tempo aqui: pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252268/… . Acha que há uma solução melhor do que a que eu respondi? Caso haja faça o favor de responder que será aceite com prazer, talvez trocar o componente currente pelo `NotFound`. (desculpe enviar mensagem mensagem aqui, não de outro jeito de falar consigo)

Answer (score 2):

O que está ocorrendo é que você deve aguardar a alteração do DOM, pois o valor que precisa está nele. O vuejs tem a solução para estes tipos de comportamento, é o `nextTick`. Este comando serve para aguardar a alteração do DOM após o codigo acima e logo que o DOM for alterado, ele será executado. Consulte a documentação [neste link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) para saber mais.

```js
Vue.component('child-comp', {
  template: '<p>Child here</p>',
  props: ['item'],
  methods: {
    alt: function() {
      alert(this.item);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      item: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    load_child: function() {
      this.item = true;

      // LINHA ADICIONADA
      this.$nextTick(function() {
        this.$refs['comp1'].alt();
      });

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="load_child">execute child</button>
  <child-comp v-bind:item="item" v-if="item != null" ref="comp1"></child-comp>
</div>
```